# Iterable to ArrayList elements change

Tags: java, hadoop, arraylist, mapreduce, iterable

So I am implementing a mapreduce job which means I am dealing with key value pairs.

I have the variable

```
Iterable<FreqDataWritable> values
```

FreqDataWritable is an object that contains pieces of information, but for now I am only concerned with one piece of information it holds which is a String which is accessed by getFilename().

I have the following loop:

```
ArrayList<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();

for(FreqDataWritable i : values) {
    filenames.add(i.getFilename());
}
```

Now all I want to do is print the values in the array list filenames.

```
for(int i = 0; i < filenames.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(filenames.get(i));
}
```

However when I do this everything in filenames is the same. The only thing printed out is a single filename printed multiple times.

My original code is more complex than this, but I simplified it for help.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  Hadoop has an odd memory usage so when I iterated over the values the first time it was just adding the same object over and over again to the arraylist.

Instead I need to do this:

```
for(FreqDataWritable i : values) {
    filenames.add(new String(i.getFilename()));
}
```

Comment: thanks for saving my life, stuck in the same issue for a week

Comment: Could you share some details/links about the memory usage you are referring to? I am stuck with a similar issue and I would like to know more about it. While this answer is a solution, doing this for complex objects can become annoying as is my case.

Comment: Since we're talking about Writable, I would suggest [Issue iterating over custom writable component in reducer
](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45873396/6162224) for future readers. Seems like a neater solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an iterator-based method?

```
Iterator i = values.iterator();
fileNames.add(i.next().getFileName());
for(i; i.hasNext();) {
    String stringI = i.next().getLast().getFileName();
    if(!stringI.equals(fileNames.get(fileNames.size() - 1)))
        fileNames.add(i.next().getLast().getFileName());
}
```

Comment: I get the same values using this approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(String filename : filenames) {
  System.out.println(fn);
}
```

Let me know if this will help?

Comment: No, this doesn't seem to work either.  I have noticed though that the last element in the arraylist is the one that gets printed multiple times.