# Issue iterating over custom writable component in reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, iterable

I am using a custom writable class as VALUEOUT in the map phase in my MR job where the class has two fields, A `org.apache.hadoop.io.Text` and `org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable`. In my reduce function I iterate through the values for each key and I perform two operations, 1. filter, 2. aggregate. In the filter, I have some rules to check if certain values in the MapWritable(with key as `Text` and value as `IntWritable` or `DoubleWritable`) satisfy certain conditions and then I simply add them to an ArrayList. At the end of the filter operation, I have a filtered list of my custom writable objects. At the aggregate phase, when I access the objects, it turns out that the last object that was successfully filtered in, has overwritten all other objects in the arraylist. After going through some similar issues with lists on SO where the last object overwrite all the others, I confirmed that I do not have static fields nor am I reusing the same custom writable by setting different values(which was quoted as the possible reasons for such an issue). For each key in the reducer I have made sure that the `CustomWritable`, `Text` key and the `MapWritable` are new objects.

In addition, I also performed a simple test by eliminating the filter & aggregate operations in my reduce and just iterated through the values and added them to an ArrayList using a for loop. In the loop, everytime I added a CustomWritable into the list, I logged the values of all the contents of the List. I logged before and after adding the element to the list. Both logs presented that the previous set of elements have been overwritten. I am confused on how this could even happen. As soon as the next element in the iterable of values was accessed by the loop `for ( CustomWritable result : values )`, the list content was modified. I am unable to figure out the reason for this behaviour. If anyone can shed some light on this, it would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed there is a similar issue here: [Iterable to ArrayList elements change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329173/iterable-to-arraylist-elements-change?rq=1). Maybe the issue is similar but there it says the same value, not sure if it is the last element or the first element accessed. Even so, I have a complex object and having to recreate a new object everytime does seem like a clumsy & painful option which I do not want to resort to. Any other better options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The"values" iterator in the reducer reuses the value as you iterate. It's a technique used for performance and smaller memory footprint. Behind the scenes, Hadoop deserializes the next record into the same Java object.  If you need to "remember" an object, you'll need to clone it.

You can take advantage of the Writable interface and use the raw bytes to populate a new object.

```
IntWritable first = WritableUtils.clone(values.next(), context.getConfiguration());
IntWritable second = WritableUtils.clone(values.next(), context.getConfiguration());
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Worked like a charm. I wonder how it works in case we use HBase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result for values since that is not a Writable class. I don't remember running into this kind of an issue with the Result object though.